# HttpPostedFileBase siempre nulo ASP.Net MVC C#

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, pdf, http-post

tengo el siguiente problema

Quiero cargar un PDF que viene desde mi vista y que llegue a mi controlador, estoy utilizando HttpPostedFileBase pero siempre llega null a mi controller

Desde herramientas para desarrolladores visualizo que si se envía el pdf pero nunca llega al controlador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mi vista tengo lo siguiente:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Facturas", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "CreateRecepcion" }))
{

    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <strong class="text-dark">Archivo</strong>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="file" accept=".pdf" required>
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="file">Buscar</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

y en mi controlador:

```
        [Route("~/Facturas/Create")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "NoFactura,NoPedido")] tblFacturas TblFacturas , HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
//codigo
}
```

ya intente con distintos pdf de distintos tamaños y siempre llega como null

Comment: Por qué no está `file` en el `Include` del [Bind](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#bind-attribute)? *Seis horas de debugging y una pregunta en stack overflow puden ahorrarte 5 minutos de leer la documentación*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo resolví de la siguiente manera

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
 @Html.ValidationSummary();
 <ol>
 <li class="lifile">
 <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="file" />
 <span class="field-validation-error" id="spanfile"></span>
 </li>
 </ol>
 <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Upload" />
}
```

FileUpload = metodo
Home = cotrolador

el controlador se quedo igual

Fuente:
[How to upload a file in ASP.MVC](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/how-to-upload-a-file-in-mvc4)